# Compressed std::expected

Tags: c++, optimization, template-specialization, std-expected

`std::expected` is a discriminated union introduced in C++23 that can be seen as a generalization of `std::optional` in that it stores an error value when `std::optional` would be empty.

Now, I figure that a lot of types already have unused storage when they are invalid or empty. A simple example would be `std::span`, which stores a pointer and a size. If the pointer is null, the size has no function and could hold an error value instead.

This would in theory offer the opportunity to optimize the memory consumption of a `std::expected<std::span>`, because there would be no need to store the discriminator (typically a bool) separately. One could use the pointer as a discriminator instead.

I am sure there are many standard and user types that would provide this opportunity when combined with `std::expected`.

This could presumably be exploited with partial template specializations for `std::expected`. If done right, it could be transparent to a user. The memory savings would be automatic, for all types that satisfy the criterium of having an existing member that can serve as the discriminator.

Now my question: Has the standard library been designed with this optimization in mind, and are there implementations that make use of this possibility? What standard types would lend themselves to this kind of optimization? Are existing standard library implementations already exploiting this opportunity?

Comment: Wouldn't std::expected be storing an arbitrary error type in the same storage? In that case, there is no value to inspect for special invalid states

Comment: "*If the pointer is null, the size has no function and could hold an error value instead.*" What would that error value represent though?

Comment: @digito_evo: The error value would be of type E as described in the definition of `std::expected`, so represents whatever E represents. I'm merely saying that the storage of E can overlap the storage of the size in `std::span`, for example.

Comment: Standard library is highly unlikely to care about saving few bytes like this. You are allowed to provide a specialisation for `std::expected` in your own program if you'd find it useful.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Pretty sure you are not allowed to specialize `std::expected`... (especially if you don't have your own type involved).

Comment: This space optimization was discussed, among committee members, regarding `std::optional`.  There were too many complications for it to move forward.

Comment: @Drew Dormann: Interesting. Have you got any details, or pointers to relevant literature?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, I guess it wouldn't be allowed to specialise on `std::span` (maybe if it was `std::span<ProgramDefinedType>`, but I'm not sure), but in general, it is allowed: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Adding_template_specializations

Comment: Even assuming one of the types is larger, and has a well-defined invalid state, wouldn't checking the inactive union member to _see_ if it's invalid be type-punning? Alternatively you need a validity-checking trait that only looks at a `byte*` prefix or whatever...

Comment: @Useless: The discriminating member would need to be outside of the union. The error type would only overlap the unused portion of T (unused in the sense that it doesn't participate in discrimination). For `std::span`, the unused portion would presumably be the size.

Comment: This is not the first time for the idea. One problem is either violating the encapsulation by exposing class internals of target class through accessor functions, or providing the accessor functions as exposition only with private/freindly access which raises scalability concerns. Another issue would be introducing type-punning in all such classes, which in turn might turn compile time evaluation of such types off. Such a modification in std will take for ever. But you may create and propose your alternative implementation to **boost** libraries.

Comment: Another point is that `std:: expected` as well as view types (like `std::span`) are meant to be used as short lived automatic objects; they're not supposed to be stored in dynamic containers. So, one important question would be if such optimization is worth the trouble? What would be the impact on execution speed?

Comment: @sh- I thought the entire point was you didn't want a discriminating member outside the union to save space. Unless you want the value type to _overlap_ the union?

Comment: My [`tiny::optional`](https://github.com/Sedeniono/tiny-optional) library is doing or allows such optimizations (as a replacement for `std::optional`). Rust's `Option` is also doing stuff like this. See the bottom of the linked GitHub page for other similar libraries that I am aware of.

Comment: Also, I see more potential for a compressed `optional` than a compressed `expected`: it is not unusual to have an `optional` as class member variable, an there might be many instances of the class. On the other hand, I think an `expected` is less commonly stored as a member. So you don't really have noticable memory savings in real applications. But maybe a compressed `expected` can be more efficiently returned from functions. Yet, I guess that often (N)RVO is already doing a good job of optimizing the return. Making it again a useless optimization attempt.